# having problem with the method findViewById

Tags: java, android, xml

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
at com.example.azerhi.My_List_View.onCreate(My_List_View.java:26)

this is the xml

````
      android:id="@+id/walidlistee"
      android:layout_width="409dp"
      android:layout_height="729dp"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />```

and this is the code 
walidList.findViewById(R.id.walidlistee);
````

Comment: You need to edit this question and add your code, So we can help.

Comment: Please post your code so we can help, the issue probably is you aren't initializing the view before doing `findViewById`

Comment: By error, it seems like you are trying to access the child view of your parent layout on your line 26. Now id of parent layout is defined properly. Please share your code for more help

Comment: yes i all ready initialized the the view

Comment: Try to clean the project and rebuild it? and please more code

Comment: I think you do not correctly inflate walidList layout so it pointing to null.

Comment: i did and nothing changed .... i what code should i write now that may be related with the problem...... i have an xml code with no erors and i called my view properly and i did initialized it and i have problem until i excute the code bom eror caused by findViewById() null  object ....

Comment: even if i did not inflate walidlist layout correctly i should not have problem with findviewbyid .... i hope i have another erors unstead of this 2 days with this daamn